# Update the quantity in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, updates

I am currently developing a P.O.S software and i started to code the pay form. But i want when the user enters the same product to increment the quantity value and not to display it on another row, i coded it but it displays the updated row and the products on the other rows

[image: Image of the actual error]

```
 public void dodadi() {
        MySqlConnection connection = Connection.prevzemiKonekcija();

        connection.Open();
        try
        {               
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBarajKod.Text))
            {
                return;
            }
            bool Found = false;
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == txtBarajKod.Text)
                    {
                        row.Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[3].Value));
                        Found = true;

                    }
                }
            }
                if(!Found)
            {
                MySqlCommand command;
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
                DataTable tabela;
                MySqlDataReader reader;

                string query = "SELECT * FROM artikli WHERE barcode  like '%" + txtBarajKod.Text + "%'";
                command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                tabela = new DataTable();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                //dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
                //adapter.Fill(tabela);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBarajKod.Text))
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    txtBarajKod.Text = reader.GetString("barcode");
                    txtNaziv.Text = reader.GetString("ProductName");
                    txtCena.Text = reader.GetString("SellPrice");
                    kolicina = 1;
                    txtKolicina.Text = kolicina.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtBarajKod.Text = "";
                    txtNaziv.Text = "";
                    txtCena.Text = "";
                    txtKolicina.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }


  private void dodadivotabela() {


        cena = float.Parse(txtCena.Text);
        kolicina = float.Parse(txtKolicina.Text);
        konecnacena = cena * kolicina;

        string prvred = txtBarajKod.Text;
        string vtorred = txtNaziv.Text;
        float tretred = cena;
        float cetvrtred = kolicina;
        float pettired = konecnacena;


        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(prvred, vtorred, tretred, cetvrtred, pettired);


    }
```

this is the second method that adds the data to the dgv

Comment: there doesnt appear to be in any code here that's adding a new record to the grid...its there more code that gets called after dodadi

Comment: yes there is , i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understood clearly, you don't want the value to show on the 4th cell of the 2nd and 3rd rows when you increment the value of the first row.

If I'm right, you should add a `break` statement in your `foreach` loop like so:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == txtBarajKod.Text)
    {
        row.Cells[3].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[3].Value));
        Found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` statement will allow you to exit your `foreach` loop once your condition is met for the first time. If you omit it it will loop over all the other rows and change the value in the 4th cell like in your screenshot because your condition is still met in the other rows.

**UPDATED**

Ok so you just need to clear your `dataGridView1` before you add your updated row to it. I presume your `dodadivotabela()` method is called when you update the row with the incremented value. Add `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()` to your method :

```
private void dodadivotabela()
{
    cena = float.Parse(txtCena.Text);
    kolicina = float.Parse(txtKolicina.Text);
    konecnacena = cena * kolicina;

    string prvred = txtBarajKod.Text;
    string vtorred = txtNaziv.Text;
    float tretred = cena;
    float cetvrtred = kolicina;
    float pettired = konecnacena;

    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(prvred, vtorred, tretred, cetvrtred, pettired);
}
```

Comment: No, i want to just increment the value of the first row if the product has the same barcode and not display it on again as in the picture

Comment: As you can see on the picture it displays the same product again even tho there is a row with the updated quantity

Comment: Ok you mean your row is being copied into a new row with the incremented value ?

Comment: Yes it copies the same row even tho there is a row with the updated quantity

Comment: This happens when you add a row to a datatable that already has data inside it. You will need to remove the "found" row from the datatable before feeding it with the "updated" row. I'm actually working on your code to come up with a proper answer. The slovenian side of it gives me difficulties haha.